# SQL issues for others but not for me? Can't keep users logged in

Tags: php, sql, security, web, pdo

I'm having a problem keeping users logged into a site I am building for someone. It works for me as intended irrespective of the account I use to login, but when asking people if it works for them the answer is unanimously no. Even other machines in my household won't login. Here's the code included on every page.

```
//maintain session
session_start();
//"renew" session for 3 more days
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60*60*24*3);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60*24*3);
//check if session data corresponds to data in SQL
if(isset($_SESSION["username"]) 
&& isset($_SESSION["password"]) 
&& isset($_SESSION["authkey"])) {
    $verifyuser = $db->prepare("
        SELECT *
            FROM users
            WHERE username = :user
            AND password = :password
            AND authkey = :authkey
    ");
    $verifyuser->execute(array(
        ':user' => $_SESSION["username"],
        ':password' => $_SESSION["password"],
        ':authkey' => $_SESSION["authkey"]));
    //if use doesn't exist, rowCount() will be 0
    if($verifyuser->rowCount() != 1) {
        session_destroy();
    }
}
//if IP stored in session doesn't match current IP, kill session
if(isset($_SESSION['ip'])){
    if($_SESSION['ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

The login page seems to work correctly (interstitial login-submit.php pages echos that login was successful), but it's below anyways.

```
//posted from login.php
$username = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];
//check SQL for user
$grabb = $db->prepare("
    SELECT username
        FROM users
        WHERE username = :username
");
$grabb->execute(array(
    ':username' => $username));
if($grabb->rowCount() == 1) {
    $grabusername = $grabb->fetchColumn();
    $pahash = crypt($password, $grabusername);
}
$logcheck = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE username = :username
        AND password = :pahash
");
$logcheck->execute(array(
    ':username' => $username,
    ':pahash' => $pahash));
//if everything is golden, initialize pertinent info into session
if ($logcheck->rowCount()==1) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $pahash;
    $_SESSION["authkey"] = $logcheck->fetchColumn(12);
    $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

I just don't understand why it works for me on this local machine but no one else. For everyone else, it says login was successful, and then on redirect it displays they're not logged in. Session isn't being stored for people other than me and I've no idea why.

A live version of the site can be seen [here](http://www.funkyvapes.ca). I've set up a dummy account (a / a) for testing purposes.

I've tried commenting out bits of code (like the IP check in the first block of code, and the entire first block of code after the php.ini lines), but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I noticed `session_start();` is in your first body of code but not the second. Is it in `login.php` as well? It needs to be in ALL pages using sessions.

Comment: `session_start();` is included in the top block of code, which is included on every single page on the site, and it appears chronologically before any other code. The second snippet of code is just that, a snippet. I excluded the `include` at the top because it's irrelevant to my question.

Comment: Perhaps your $_SESSION['ip'] isn't getting set up properly (and has previously set up right on your computer) and you destroy the session because it doesn't match.  I'd echo or errorlog those values to see if you're getting something other than you expect.

Comment: @starshine531: I think I should append the approaches I tried to the OP, but I have tried to comment out bits of code to see the troublesome area and no dice. Commenting out the IP check, commenting out the entire first block of code below the php.ini bits doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried destroying your session on your computer (clear the cookies if you don't have another way)?  If after that you log in and it fails on your computer, then you'll be a step closer to fixing it.

Comment: Good suggestion: I tried it and now I, too, experience the problem. While I now can troubleshoot while checking myself (instead of relying on others to tell me if it's fixed or not), I'm not particularly closer to solving the issue. At this point I believe something is wrong with my php.ini.

Comment: @riista I'm starting to wonder about your `ip` session checking, and thinking that IP addresses may be constantly changing and reset by an ISP. I stand at being wrong, yet something is definitely not matching.

Comment: @riista I also tested your "test" page and it automatically refreshed after 3 secs., and was no longer logged in, just so you know.

Comment: Yes. `login-submit.php` redirects to `index.php` after 3 seconds. This is intended. It is supposed to keep `$_SESSION` data across all pages, but as you can tell it doesn't. I can't see the IP check being a problem. If I comment out that segment it still doesn't login.

Comment: @riista How are you defining your session names? I only see `if` conditions, but no session names. For example `$_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;`

Comment: @riista Actually scratch that --^ it's in your 2nd body of code.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: @riista If a session name is pre-defined, then you have something to match it with, that's what I meant by that.

Comment: @riista Try putting this `$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`  under `session_start();`

Comment: This is odd, but I removed `<!DOCTYPE html>` from the top of my page and it works now. Why would this make a difference? Is it because it appears before `session_start()`? edit; actually, it logs me in, but then logs me right out about 20~ seconds later.

Comment: @riista I would think that it may be because it's considered as output, and you can't have output before headers.

Comment: Yes, doctype has to be the first item in the sphere of html, but php happens before html does.  And session_start() must be the first thing on the page.

Comment: It looks like you've resolved your issue.  Feel free to answer your own question. So other people know it's been answered.

Comment: Well, I've solved one problem but created another: `$_SESSION` doesn't stay alive very long despite the ini_sets declaring it populated for 3 days. Thank you for both of your help in solving my issue, I can take it from here (I hope).

Comment: @riista I was logged in for about a minute till it kicked me out once I clicked on "account" or `bug report`, can't remember for sure. And you're welcome.

Comment: Yes, that is the new issue. Thanks for checking for me, though.

Comment: Heh, that's what programming looks like.  You solve one problem and then find you have another one. :-D  I'd try removing your ini_sets and see if that fixes the problem. (by default sessions last about 24 minutes)

Comment: The good 'ol days of `debug` - `command.com` and 3.5" floppies! Things were so much simpler then. lol

Comment: Strange, but I changed `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60*60*24*3);` from `60*60*24*3` to just `259200` and it seems to be working. Some strangeness going on with PHP I guess, since either should produce the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that `<!DOCTYPE html>` was before `session_start();`, resulting in session data not being maintained from page to page.